# Can Expectation-Maximization algorithm estimate parameters other than mean and variance (from a model distribution)?

Tags: bayesian, optimization, expectation-maximization

We know that we can use Expectation-Maximization algorithm to estimate parameters from a Gaussian mixture model, say $\mu$, $\sigma$, and $\phi$ (they are parameters of the Gaussian distributions)as from here: http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes7b.pdf.

But my question is, if I have other parameters in the model, other than the parameters of the distributions, like some parameters of a certain property I want to estimate, (like any parameter, such as a parameter of image translation in the model etc...) can I still use EM? And my case is not a clustering problem, as I have seem EM is mostly used for.

Any reference is welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: EM is used to find the MLE of the parameters of a latent variable model, whatever the meaning of these parameters.

Comment: @Xi'anThanks! Any ideas on how to do the "M" step? i.e., how to find the maximization? (what kind of optimization to do the maximization?) and a closed form solution for estimating the parameters? Taking derivatives?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please provide a model where you face difficulties with EM.

Comment: @Ian I recommend looking at the original EM paper by Dempster, Laird and Rubin ("Maximum Likelihood from Incomplete Data via the EM Algorithm", *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B* (1977), **39** (1), 1-38). It answers your posted question almost immediately and discusses some relevant aspects of your comment.